# Removing breakpoints from Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I have inherited a web app that's using Bootstrap 3 as its framework with some basic customisation applied via the recommended `_custom-variables.scss` method. The official SASS port is added as a dependency and included in the `app.scss` file using `@import "bootstrap";` after `_custom-variables.scss` and `_custom-mixins.scss`.

The fluid-width app will not be usable on small screens (due to the sheer amount of data being displayed) so I want to disable or remove the `-xs-` and `-sm-` breakpoints from the CSS. The layout will be optimised for `-lg-` and `-md-` breakpoints with `-md-` being the narrowest breakpoint.

In `_custom-variables.scss`, I changed the `$container-tablet` width from:

```
// Small screen / tablet
$container-tablet:             (720px + $grid-gutter-width) !default;
//** For `$screen-sm-min` and up.
$container-sm:                 $container-tablet !default;

// Medium screen / desktop
$container-desktop:            (940px + $grid-gutter-width) !default;
//** For `$screen-md-min` and up.
$container-md:                 $container-desktop !default;
```

to:

```
// Small screen / tablet
$container-tablet:             (940px + $grid-gutter-width) !default;
//** For `$screen-sm-min` and up.
$container-sm:                 $container-tablet !default;

// Medium screen / desktop
$container-desktop:            (940px + $grid-gutter-width) !default;
//** For `$screen-md-min` and up.
$container-md:                 $container-desktop !default;
```

I also set a `min-width: $container-md;` on the parent`<div>` wrapping the entire layout.

This works so long as I include classes for the unwanted breakpoints on my HTML elements. For example the following maintains a column width of 25%:

`<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">`

but omitting the smaller breakpoint classes removes the `width` property and the `<div>` defaults to a width of 100% when the browser shrinks below 992px (the `min-width` value of the `-md-` breakpoint).

## My questions:

1. Why do I need to specify the additional smaller breakpoint classes on my containers? (My Bootstrap skills are rusty!)
2. Is there a better way of removing/disabling the two smaller breakpoints?

Answer (score 1):

You only change `container` width, that's why you have to specify smaller breakpoint classes.

Try to change breakpoint itself:

```
@screen-md:                  1px;
@screen-md-min:              @screen-md;
```

And you should specify min-width for `container` manually:

```
@media (min-width: 1px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
```

## [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/PzXzky)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as I was referencing each Bootstrap partial I needed individually in `app.scss`, I took a similar approach to how you apply your own variables when themeing Bootstrap.

1. I made a copy of `bootstrap/grid.scss` and named it `bootstrap/custom-grid.scss`
2. In `app.scss`, I swapped out the reference to `bootstrap/grid.scss` with the reference to `bootstrap/custom-grid.scss`
3. Inside `bootstrap/custom-grid.scss` I removed the following lines:

...

```
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    width: $container-sm;
}

@include make-grid(xs);


@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    @include make-grid(sm);
}

@media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
    @include make-grid(md);
}
```